# Rolling Stack Upgrade on a Catalyst 3850

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, cisco-ios, stacking

I'm looking to do an IOS upgrade on a two Switch 3850 stack, with minimum downtime.

As our servers all have redundant uplinks to each switch, it would be preferable to reload each stack member individually. Unfortunately all the documentation I've read so far implies the entire stack needs to reload at the same time.

So my Question is: Can the IOS be upgraded on a 3850 Stack, without a complete outage? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: What version are you upgrading to and from?

Comment: 03.02.02.SE to 03.03.03.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, sorry.  That's why I prefer daisy-chaining to stacking, even though I lose out on some bandwidth and a couple of ports.

There are some helpful hints on the upgrade here, though:

https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11924636/3850-stack-ios-upgrade